# Request a lot of URLs with asyncio

Tags: request, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a list of 30,000 URLs and for each of the URLs of this list, I want obtain a list which contains the text of the page for every URL.

For this I use asyncio, it's already faster than with requests, but it still a little slow for me (10 minutes for 30,000 URLs).
Do you think that I can change something in my code that would make it faster?

My code:

```
async def main(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, timeout=False) as resp:
        text = await resp.text()
        return text



async def obtain_text_from_url(urls, list_text):

    my_conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=200)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=my_conn) as session:

    tasks = []
    for url in source_boamp:
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(main(session, url)))

    tasks2 = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    for task in tasks2:
        list_text.append(task)
    return list_text
```

and the function that I launch on the list of URLs to obtain what I want:

```
def launch(urls):
    list_text = []
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(obtain_text_from_url(urls, liste_text))
    return liste_text
```

Comment: You're running with a max of 200 connections at a time. If each request takes a couple of seconds to complete, that  easily ends up being around 10 minutes (30000/200*2). The only change you can make here is increasing the number of simultaneous connections (the `limit` parameter for `aiohttp.TCPConnector`).

Comment: I change the limit but it didn't change nothing with the time of execution....

Comment: I am a little surprised, but I don't have an easy way of testing this out locally.